# How to manage pdf table height using iTextSharp using asp.net 2010 though c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I can not set pdf table height using `iTextSharp` through asp.net 2010 with c#. If I set fixed height of any cell to 15, then the data of the cell does not show. In this case the cell showing without data. I want to change the height of cell less than *15px* and show the data also in the cell.

```
private void CreatePDF()
{
    string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy.HHmmss");
    string pdfFileName = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "\\Files\\" + "PDFCreation_Reporting_" + timestamp + ".pdf";
    Document myDocument = new Document(PageSize.A4, 5, 20, 50, 25);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(myDocument, new FileStream(pdfFileName, FileMode.Create));
    myDocument.Open();
    PdfPTable UpperTable1 = new PdfPTable(3);
    PdfPTable UpperTable2 = new PdfPTable(3);
    PdfPCell utcell1 = new PdfPCell();
    PdfPCell utcell2 = new PdfPCell();
    PdfPCell utcell3 = new PdfPCell();
    PdfPCell utcell4 = new PdfPCell();
    PdfPCell utcell5 = new PdfPCell();
    PdfPCell utcell6 = new PdfPCell();
    utcell1.FixedHeight = 15f;
    utcell2.FixedHeight = 15f;
    utcell3.FixedHeight = 15f;
    utcell1.Padding = 0;
    utcell2.Padding = 0;
    utcell3.Padding = 0;

    utcell4.FixedHeight = 15f;
    utcell5.FixedHeight = 15f;
    utcell6.FixedHeight = 15f;
    utcell4.Padding = 0;
    utcell5.Padding = 0;
    utcell6.Padding = 0;

    float[] colWidthsut1 = { 800, 685, 800 };//35%,30%,35% [2285]
    UpperTable1.SetWidths(colWidthsut1);
    UpperTable1.WidthPercentage = 100;

    float[] colWidthsut2 = { 457, 1028, 800 };//20%,45%,35% [2285]
    UpperTable2.SetWidths(colWidthsut2);
    UpperTable2.WidthPercentage = 100;

    string strTest1 = "Test data";
    string strTest2 = "Test data";
    string strTest3 = "Test Data";
    string strTest4 = "Test data";
    string strTest5 = "";
    string strTest6 = "";

    Phrase phrTest1 = new Phrase();
    Phrase phrTest2 = new Phrase();
    Phrase phrTest3 = new Phrase();
    Phrase phrTest4 = new Phrase();
    Phrase phrTest5 = new Phrase();
    Phrase phrTest6 = new Phrase();

    phrTest1.Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 6, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
    phrTest2.Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 6, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
    phrTest3.Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 6, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);
    phrTest4.Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 6, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

    phrTest1.Add(strTest1);
    phrTest2.Add(strTest2);
    phrTest3.Add(strTest3);
    phrTest4.Add(strTest4);
    phrTest5.Add(strTest5);
    phrTest6.Add(strTest6);
    utcell1.AddElement(phrTest1);
    utcell2.AddElement(phrTest2);
    utcell3.AddElement(phrTest3);
    utcell4.AddElement(phrTest4);
    utcell5.AddElement(phrTest5);
    utcell6.AddElement(phrTest6);

    PdfPCell[] firstrowCells = { utcell1, utcell2, utcell3 };
    PdfPRow row1 = new PdfPRow(firstrowCells);
    UpperTable1.Rows.Add(row1);
    PdfPCell[] secondrowCells = { utcell4, utcell5, utcell6 };
    PdfPRow row2 = new PdfPRow(secondrowCells);
    UpperTable2.Rows.Add(row2);

    myDocument.Add(UpperTable1);
    myDocument.Add(UpperTable2);
    myDocument.Close();
}
```

Comment: If you really weant help, please provide sample code (short and easy to compile) to demonstrate what you do and what fails.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could modify the margines, that worked for me.
Also, when do you modify the cell? Maybe you are doing it after adding it to the table? Then it will probably not work...

Answer (score 0):

FileStream file = new FileStream(newFullPath, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);   // Create a byte array of file stream length
        //byte[] ImageData = new byte[file.Length];   //Read block of bytes from stream into the byte array
        //file.Read(ImageData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(file.Length));   //Close the File Stream

```
    //  string appPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
    CheckBox1.Visible = false;
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    string appPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
   // FileStream file = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/save/") + (Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["cust"])) + "_" + (n++) + ".PDF", FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    pnlPerson.RenderControl(hw);

    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 5, 20, 50, 25);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    //   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, file);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    hw.Close();
    sw.Close();
    pdfDoc.Close();
    sr.Close();
    file.Close();
    htmlparser.Close();
```